# Is Wifi direct available in the iPhone 4 or in iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, ios4, wifi-direct

Can any one suggest a Wifi direct technology supported on an iPhone 4s or iOS 5?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly not supported by iOS5: I didn't see API support for that. And I also don't think it is supported by iPhone 4S too.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Wifi Direct on iOS as of iOS 5.1 and the iPhone 4S, however you can always use Bluetooth.