# Can I use wi-fi direct api in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, wifi-direct

I want find a friend nearby me by using wi-fi direct in my application .So could you tell me How can I use the wi-fi direct api if ios is suppored this ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether iOS supports Wi-Fi direct or not.
I found an open-source library for doing this [**alljoyn**](https://www.alljoyn.org/). I'm not sure about this, because I didn't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914144/what-wifi-direct-libraries-exist) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118840/is-wifi-direct-available-in-the-iphone-4-or-in-ios-5), Wi-Fi direct is not available at the moment (i.e. iOS 6.x). But as AirDrop (which may be seen as using Wi-Fi direct) will be part of iOS7, you may use this feature at a later point in time.